# How to set JDK 19 Oracle for AWS Cloud9 by option (not by install)?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I checked

```
ec2-user:~/environment $ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.17.8.1 (build 11.0.17+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.17.8.1 (build 11.0.17+8-LTS, mixed mode)
ec2-user:~/environment $ javac --version
javac 11.0.17
ec2-user:~/environment $
```

[image]

How to set JDK 19 Oracle for AWS Cloud9 by option (not by install)?

Comment: By definition, the Cloud 9 development environment is managed by Amazon.  At this time they are using a Java 11 compatible environment.  This makes sense as Java 19 won't be supported in a few months where Java 11 will be supported for several more years.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what [environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/ec2-env-versus-ssh-env.html) you're using, but in either case of EC2, or SSH, you'll **need** to install JDK 19 using the appropriate OS package manager, or tools such as SDKMan. Gradle nor the IDE will download it for you, nor will it be the default as long as Java 11 (or 17) are considered LTS. Best to create your own AMI with it pre-installed.

Or otherwise, use a Dockerfile with Gradle and JDK 19 to compile and/or run your code.